How to get the event div position in daypilot
I am using daypilot calendar scheduler. I want, when i click an event a pop up box come near of it left align. For this i need its div position on the browser. How can i get it?. The things i want is concept of google calendar. I want to implement their viewing, editing and deleting event features.
Html part
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="event-popup" class="popup"></div>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="main">
                        <div class="left">
                            <div id="datepicker"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="p1"></p>
                        <div class="right">
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <button id="previous">Previous</button>
                                <button id="today">Today</button>
                                <button id="next">Next</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="calendar"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

onEventClick: async function (args) {

    const eventData = args.e.data;
    console.log(eventData);
}

this is my event click function inside calendar object.
I tried the method we use in JavaScript, but it is not working. I tried writing html in modal. its also not work as i trying to do.

Please share html code as well.

added the html here

Please visit [ask] and make a [mcve]
